# Transter custom object from Apple watch to iPhone using updateApplicationContext

Tags: swift, dictionary, watchkit, data-transfer

I'm new to Swift and started my first app.

I'm trying to transfer data from the Apple watch to the iPhone using updateApplicationContext, but only get an error:

```
[WCSession updateApplicationContext:error:]_block_invoke failed due to WCErrorCodePayloadUnsupportedTypes
```

This is the code in my WatchKit Extension:

```
var transferData = [JumpData]()

func transferDataFunc() {
    let applicationDict = ["data":self.transferData]
    do {
        try self.session?.updateApplicationContext(applicationDict)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

These are the object structure I want to send:

```
class AltiLogObject {

let altitude : Float
let date : Date

init (altitude: Float) {
    self.altitude = altitude
    self.date = Date.init()
}

init (altitude: Float, date : Date) {
    self.altitude = altitude
    self.date = date
}

}

class JumpData {

let date : Date
let altitudes : [AltiLogObject]

init(altitudes: [AltiLogObject]) {
    self.altitudes = altitudes
    self.date = Date.init()
}
init(altitudes: [AltiLogObject], date : Date) {
    self.date = date
    self.altitudes = altitudes
}
}
```

To have it complete, the code of the receiver function:

```
private func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let transferData = applicationContext["data"] as! [JumpData]

    //Use this to update the UI instantaneously (otherwise, takes a little while)
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.jumpDatas += transferData
    }
}
```

Any hints are welcome, as I'm trying to get it running for over a week now.

Answer (score 3):

You can only send property list values through updateApplicationContext() - the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615621-updateapplicationcontext%20%E2%80%9Cdocumentation%E2%80%9D) states this but it isn’t clear at all.

The type of objects that you can send can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html

Obviously your custom object types aren’t supported, so what you need to do is to break the properties down into the constituent parts (e.g your altitude and date properties), send them individually in the applicationContext dictionary passed into updateApplicationContext() and then reconstruct the objects on the receiving end.

It’s a real pain of course, but that’s the way this all works.

HTH

Comment: the other option would be to serialize the objects to Data, and then deserialize them on the other side. Not much different than just John's suggestion of breaking them down in to constituent parts.

Comment: This is probably a better suggestion than mine!